# Error trying to use codedeploy to load code onto a auto scalable group of EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-auto-scaling

When I try to run codedeploy, I get the following error :

The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are experiencing problems.

When I look at the ec2 instances created by the auto scalable group, they are both running, and status is passed 2/2 checks passed in green. I am wondering if this is just a catch all error, because its supposed to throw this error if one or both or all are not running.

Comment: ssh to the instances and check inside what's happening.

Comment: Thanks for the reply .It was nothing to do with the instances. It was a missing appspec.yml. The error message was very misleading.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it wanted an appspec.yml. I am not sure why a appspec.yml is needed, If you create the autodeploy group, and create the codedeploy application, why is there a need for a appspec.yml. I am using jenkins to run the code deploy. I gave it a appspec.yml that is empty, and seems to work.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.